# C# WPF Datagrid how to disable selection cell on specific column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, selection

Brand new here on SO and brand new with WPF datagrid.

I have been searching in all opened threads concerning Datagrid but I can't find any answers to my problem.

I'm trying to display datas into a datagrid. So far so good.
I'm trying to let user select cells in datagrid. So far so good.
I want to disable selection cells on specifics columns.

See image in link.

How can disable selection cells on Torque columns or Average column and let the user select only cells on columns `Mes1` `Mes2` `Mes3`

[image: Example of the datagrid]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to prevent cells in certain columns from being selected, you could use a `DataGridCell` style that sets the `IsHitTestVisible` property of these cells to `true`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Torque">
                    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Average">
                    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

> I am just playing with the code. But when I click on a cell in for example Column Mes 1, and then use keyboard to navigate, cells of column Torque and Average can be focused :-(

I guess you will have to set the `IsEnabled` property to `false` then:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Torque">
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: I am just playing with the code. But when I click on a cell in for example Column Mes 1, and then use keyboard to navigate, cells of column Torque and Average can be focused :-(

Answer (score 2):

One can use [CellTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celltemplate(v=vs.110).aspx), In the example below one of the columns cells will be an image:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```